# WordPress multisite redirect one custom non www domain to www

Tags: multisite, redirect

I have a multisite setup where I have a mix of custom domains and subdomains of the primary site.
The majority of my custom domains automatically redirect from `www` to non `www` but I have one client that wants it to work the other way, i.e. you type `somedomain.com` and it redirects to to `www.somedomain.com`.

I've tried the mu-domain-mapping plugin which made me remove the `COOKIE_DOMAIN` constant, removing that prevented custom domains being able to log in (they got a cookies not enabled error).

Is there a way to do this natively in WordPress multisite?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a rewrite rule just for his domain

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.somedomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

updated my answer because I misread the question.

Comment: I would rather not use .htaccess if possible. Also, I think this would be the rule:

```RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^somdomain.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.somdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]```

Comment: @greg Do you have access to Apache virtual hosts? Those are the best ways. A PHP redirect will be a hack method. You could update the config in WordPress admin. https://namecheap.simplekb.com//SiteContents/2-7C22D5236A4543EB827F3BD8936E153E/media/wp_url_1.png